# Has this operator $0$ as an eigenvalue / where is my error?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

I know of a theorem that tells me, that every compact linear operator
on an infinitedimensional Hilbert space has to have the eigenvalue
$0$. On the other hand I have the operator 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 & T:\ell^{2}\rightarrow\ell^{2}\\
 & \left(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots\right)\mapsto\left(\lambda_{1}x_{1},\lambda_{2}x_{2},\ldots\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\left(\lambda_{n}\right)_{n}$ is a sequence of real nonnegative
numbers, tending to $0$. Then this mapping can't have $0$ as an
eigenvalue, since if that were the case, there had to be a $\left(y_{1},y_{2},\ldots\right)\in\ell^{2}$
with not all $y_{n}$'s being zero, such that $\lambda_{n}y_{n}=0$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $\lambda_{n}\neq0$, that would imply
that all $y_{n}$'s are there.

Where is my error ? The operator $T$ is compact and $\ell^{2}$ is
infinitedimensional, so this should be a counterexample to the theorem
above.

Comment: The theorem does not say that $0$ is an eigenvalue, only that the spectrum contains $0$.  See Cocopuff's answer.

Comment: Unlike in finite dimensions, an operator can have a residual and continuous spectrum. The operator may be injective but not surjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$0$ being in the spectrum means that $T$ isn't invertible, which in infinite-dimensional space no longer means that it's not injective.  You should be able to show that $T$ isn't surjective.

Comment: You might want to replace the word bijective by the word invertible.

Comment: @Rasmus Alright. They should be the same in Banach spaces, though.

Comment: Right, [this theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem) helps us out.

Comment: @Cocopuffs So just to gmake sure I understood this properly: $0$ is in the spectrum, since $T$ isn't surjectiv, but since $0$, as I have shown, isn't an eigenvalue, $T$ has to be injective ?

Comment: @user36675 Right, $0$ is only an approximate eigenvalue

Comment: @user36675: Related info: Compact operators on infinite dimensional spaces are never surjective (although they can be injective as in your example).  All *nonzero* elements of the spectrum of a compact operator are eigenvalues (e.g. see the [Fredholm alternative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_alternative)).